# filtering inappropriate content ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, spam

I am writing a rails application with lots of registered users, interactions and generated content. Can anyone recommend some techniques or guidelines for fighting inappropriate content and spam, for example for comments, images and that kind of content?

I stared with "report" link for me to review content later and wanted to introduce default_scope's for models I think that default_scope isn't the best idea

Comment: [this discussion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5189410/preventing-link-spamming-through-forms-on-rails/6112385#6112385) on SO can help

Answer (score 1):

You could look at the concept of Classifier. Here's a short list of Ruby related links:

- [Bayes Classification in Ruby](http://www.igvita.com/2007/05/23/bayes-classification-in-ruby/)
- [Naive Bayesian Classifiers and Ruby](http://blog.saush.com/2009/02/11/naive-bayesian-classifiers-and-ruby/)
- [Ruby classifier gem](http://classifier.rubyforge.org/)

Just a starting point. The topic is huge.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [captcha](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/rails_captcha) its not a complete solution, but would reduce spam significantly

Comment: I am referring to user generated content, and not fighting spam bots or such. For example if someone posts inappropriate image what are the best ways for filtering that kind of content

Comment: you can make each pictures have to pass checks, and people with admin roles check contents, and for text have a validation on text that are not allowed in user content